# Was heißt der rote Punkt vor »Low Quality Posts« im Review-Queue-Drop-down-Menü?

Tags: support, review

Den roten Punkt im Drop-down-Menü der Review Queue habe ich auch in anderen Stacks schon gesehen, aber nicht weiter beachtet.
Hier ist er jedoch erst kürzlich erschienen.
Er ist sogar dann zu sehen, wenn überhaupt keine Dinge abzuarbeiten sind.

Was bedeutet der Punkt, warum verschwindet er nicht, wenn es nichts zu tun gibt, und wieso wurde er eingeführt?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Der rote Punkt signalisiert Dringlichkeit. Er wird für die ganze Seite berechnet und nicht für den einzelnen Nutzer. Es wird also ignoriert, wenn Du Reviews nicht durchführen kannst, z. B. weil Du schon reviewt hast, die auslösende Flagge von Dir stammt, oder sie Deine eigenen Beiträge betreffen. Daher kann es sein, dass Du trotz roten Punktes kein Review zu erledigen hast.